Did Judas believe and profess that Jesus is the Son of Man?
Did Judas believe and profess that Jesus is the Son of Man?
Matthew 26:24 (New American Standard Bible):

The Son of Man is going away just as it is written about Him; but woe to that man by whom the Son of Man is betrayed! It would have been good for that man if he had not been born.”

Jesus is specifically saying, woe to that man who will betray Him as the "Son of Man".
Did Judas believe that Jesus is the Son of Man?
Looking further at the passages, Judas looked upon Jesus only as "Rabbi".
Matthew 26:23–25 (Berean Standard Bible):

23 Jesus answered, “The one who has dipped his hand into the bowl with Me will betray Me.
24 The Son of Man will go just as it is written about Him, but woe to that man by whom He is betrayed. It would be better for him if he had not been born.”
25 Then Judas, who would betray Him, said, “Surely not I, Rabbi?” Jesus answered, “You have said it yourself.”

In Matthew 26:23, Did Judas dip his hand into the bowl?
And in Matthew 26:25, Judas denied that he is the Son of Perdition. And Jesus said, "You have said it yourself", as if saying, it is not you Judas.
Judas, all throughout Jesus ministry, looked upon Jesus only as "Rabbi".
Did Judas believe and profess that Jesus is the Son of Man?

I don't know what translation you are using (because you did not specify) but 'surely' is not in the Greek Text, see Biblehub. A better translation of Matthew 26:25 would be : 'It isn't me, is it ?' To which Jesus replies, 'You said it'. (I am being deliberately colloquial, more so than I would normally be, for the sake of clarity.) This is quite clear. Judas asks if it is himself and Jesus confirms that it is so. I have corrected the (in my view) unnecessary down-vote but I suggest that more clarity of detail is required.

Judas is featured prominently in the Matins of Holy Friday... The darkening of Judas' nouse is expounded upon with the reoccurring refrain, "Judas did not understand" which appears throughout Antiphon III.
So I don't think Judas truly believed. He routinely sinned around Jesus. And despite everything Jesus let him perform miracles, and even then... he still betrayed Him. It is a great mystery how this occurred...

Did you want a Catholic answer? Afterall you tagged it Catholicism. Yet you employed translations (Berean Standard Bible) that are not normally recognized by the Church as acceptable translations used by various episcopal councils.

It has become fashionable of late to give Judas Iscariot a character makeover. Some feel quite sorry for him, offer reasons why he 'slipped up' by betraying Jesus, and hopefully expect him to get into the kingdom of God nonetheless. Well, the details in Matthew's gospel are significant and state a few uncomfortable facts about this man.
The phrase "Son of Man" is certainly important, especially in Matthew's gospel account, and Judas seemed to have no difficulty accepting the humanity of Jesus. Later on, Paul warned against people who would deny the humanity of Christ. But the key phrase that identifies all Christians is to acclaim this Son of Man as their Lord. That is stated by Paul where he writes that nobody, by the Holy Spirit can say, 'Jesus be cursed', just as nobody can say 'Jesus is Lord' except by the Holy Spirit. (1 Cor. 12:3)
Yes, Judas was out to betray the man, Jesus, but if he had believed this man to also be the Son of God, would he have dared? Even the rulers responsible for the crucifixion of Jesus did not really know who it was they were crucifying (1 Cor. 2:8). Apostles like Peter did acclaim Jesus as the Christ, the Son of God (Mat. 16:16) and Jesus rejoiced at that confession, for the Father had revealed that truth to Peter. No such divine revelation was given to Judas. This can be seen from the words of explanation in this commentary:

"There are few blacker pages in all history than the character and
conduct of Judas Iscariot: there is no more awful evidence of the
wickedness of man... Let us learn from these verses, that a man may
enjoy great privileges, and make a great religious profession, and yet
his heart all the time may not be right before God.
Judas Iscariot had the highest possible religious privileges. He was a
chosen apostle, and companion of Christ: he was an eye-witness of our
Lord's miracles, and a hearer of His sermons; he saw what Abraham and
Moses never saw, and heard what David and Isaiah never heard; he lived
in the society of the eleven Apostles; but for all this his heart was
never changed. He clung to one darling sin [love of money].
Judas Iscariot made a reputable profession of religion: there was
nothing but what was right, and proper, and becoming in his outward
conduct. Like the other Apostles, he appeared to believe and to give
up all for Christ's sake: like them, he was sent forth to preach and
work miracles. No one of the eleven seems to have suspected him of
hypocrisy. When our Lord said, 'One of you shall betray Me', no one
said, 'Is it Judas?' Yet all this time his heart was never
changed...
Let us learn in the last place from these verses, the hopeless
condition of all who die unconverted. Jesus says of Judas, 'It had
been good for that man if he had not been born.' This saying admits of
only one interpretation. It teaches plainly that it is better never to
live at all, than to live without faith, and to die without grace. To
die in this state is to be ruined forevermore: it is a fall from which
there is no rising; it is a loss which is utterly irretrievable. There
is no change in hell: the gulf between hell and heaven is one that no
man can pass. This saying could never have been used if there was any
truth in the doctrine of universal salvation." Expository Thoughts on
Matthew, J.C. Ryle, pp 350-1 & 353 Banner of Truth 1986, original
1856

Matthew 23:25 can never be misconstrued to mean that Jesus denied Judas to be his betrayer, nor did Judas deny it. He may have hoped that by asking, "Is it me?" Jesus might say, "No" and so calm his anxiety that he was about to be exposed. Jesus' response allayed that fear and sent him scurrying out into the night, confident that he would get the promised 30 pieces of silver. Yet Jesus had known long before that night which one of the Twelve was a devil - John 6:70.
The answer is that, whatever Judas believed Jesus to be, he did not believe Jesus to be his Lord; he did not have believing, saving faith in the Son of Man, the Messiah, as the Son of God.

According to Catholicism, did Judas believe and profess that Jesus is the Son of Man?
The short answer is yes and no.
Judas believed that Jesus was the Son of Man, but did not profess such a belief, at least not publicly or according to the Gospels?

The Son of man indeed goeth, as it is written of him: but woe to that man by whom the Son of man shall be betrayed: it were better for him, if that man had not been born. Matthew 26:24 DRA

In the Gospels, Jesus noted that he was the Son of Man. A point that Judas Iscariot never denied. Judas remained an Apostle of Christ, even after hearing some of the more harder subject matters to digest that Jesus had preached to the people.
True that many thought Jesus was simply a rabbi, but his intimate disciples truly understood that Jesus was indeed the Son of Man.

Jesus Deepens the Scandal: Eat My Flesh, Drink My Blood (6:52-59)
When Jesus mentions his flesh, the tension in the crowd increases. The people are not just grumbling (v. 41); they are arguing sharply with one another (v. 52). Once again we see people who come to Jesus as a rabbi, who even wanted to make him king, but who are far from treating him as either a king or a rabbi. They are not receiving his teaching, as cryptic and offensive as it is. Like Nicodemus, they can only ask how such a thing can be (v. 52; cf. 3:9). "When questioning concerning the `how' comes in, there comes in with it unbelief" (Chrysostom In John 46.2). And Jesus does not make it easy for them. He now makes sure they get the point that real eating and drinking are involved. As he deepens the offense in these verses, he also explains in a very profound way the eternal life he is offering.
Jesus begins by revealing more sharply our need of the life he offers: I tell you the truth, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood, you have no life in you (v. 53). He claims that the life he is talking about is not merely some optional gift that we can afford to ignore. Apart from the life he offers, we are dead. Here is a claim as demanding as are his earlier claims about his own identity and what he offers to those who believe in him (vv. 30-51). Our utter neediness is seen clearly when set against the greatness of his offer: Whoever eats my flesh and drinks my blood has eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last day (v. 54). Jesus is promising a new quality of life now and resurrection in the future.

Judas remained the midst of all of Jesus’ preaching and along with all the other disciples stayed at his side, for Christ was obviously the Son of Man!
The most chilling question proposed to Judas by Christ was not whether he denied he was the Son of Man, but rather was he betraying his Master with a kiss?

St. John likewise lays stress on the instigation of the evil spirit: "the devil having now put into the heart of Judas Iscariot, the son of Simon, to betray him" (13:2). The same Evangelist, as we have seen, tells of an earlier intimation of Christ's foreknowledge of the betrayal (John 6:71-2), and in the same chapter says expressly: "For Jesus knew from the beginning, who they were that did not believe, and who he was, that would betray him" (6:65). But he agrees with the Synoptics in recording a more explicit prediction of the treachery at the Last Supper: "When Jesus had said these things, he was troubled in spirit; and he testified, and said: Amen, amen I say to you, one of you shall betray me" (John 12:21). And when St. John himself, at Peter's request, asked who this was, "Jesus answered: He it is to whom I shall reach bread dipped. And when he had dipped the bread, he gave it to Judas Iscariot, the son of Simon. And after the morsel, Satan entered into him. And Jesus said to him: That which thou dost, do quickly. Now no man at the table knew to what purpose he said this unto him. For some thought, because Judas had the purse, that Jesus said to him: Buy those things which we have need of for the festival day: or that he should give something to the poor" (12:26-9). These last details about the words of Jesus, and the natural surmise of the disciples, are given only by St. John. But the prediction and the questioning of the disciples are recorded by all the Synoptics (Matthew 26; Mark 14; Luke 22). St. Matthew adds that Judas himself asked, "Is it I, Rabbi?" and was answered: "Thou hast said it" (26:25).
All four Evangelists agree in regard to the main facts of the actual betrayal which followed so closely on this prediction, and tell how the traitor came with a multitude or a band of soldiers from the chief priests, and brought them to the place where, as he knew, Jesus would be found with His faithful disciples (Matthew 26:47; Mark 14:43; Luke 22:47; John 18:3). But some have details not found in the other narratives. That the traitor gave a kiss as a sign is mentioned by all the Synoptics, but not by St. John, who in his turn is alone in telling us that those who came to take Jesus fell backward to the ground as He answered "I am he." Again, St. Mark tells that Judas said "Hail, Rabbi" before kissing his Master, but does not give any reply. St. Matthew, after recording these words and the traitor's kiss, adds: "And Jesus said to him: Friend, whereto art thou come:" (26:50). St. Luke (22:48) gives the words: "Judas, dost thou betray the Son of man with a kiss?"
Judas Iscariot (Catholic Encyclopaedia)

Judas knew who Jesus was.

Victorian art critic John Ruskin argues that Judas was not only greedy and dishonest, but stupid as well, and that is why he acted as he did:

Stupidity is always the basis of the Judas bargain.
We do great injustice to Iscariot, in thinking him wicked above all common wickedness. He was only a common money-lover, and, like all money-lovers, did not understand Christ;-could not make out the worth of Him, or meaning of Him.
He never thought He would be killed. He was horror-struck when he found that Christ would be killed; threw his money away instantly, and hanged himself.
... Judas was a common, selfish, muddle-headed, pilfering fellow; his hand always in the bag of the poor, not caring for them.
Helpless to understand Christ, he yet believed in Him, much more than most of us do; had seen Him do miracles, thought He was quite strong enough to shift for Himself, and he, Judas, might as well make his own little bye-perquisites out of the affair. Christ would come out of it well enough, and he have his thirty pieces. (Source: BBC article quoting John Ruskin).

There is another theory that Judas belonged to the Zealots group which was seeking emancipation of Jews from Roman clutches by way of violent revolt. Judas first expected that Jesus would be a fit leader for the revolt, he being able to perform great miracles. Sooner or later, Judas would realise that Jesus was not the one his group was looking forward to,  and decided to make some bucks by handing the Master over to the Jewish leaders.
That said, is it not possible that Jesus spoke of himself as Son of Man in front of Judas, with a purpose? Was he not telling Judas that he was not going to use his powers in the capacity of Son of God to escape from the tormentors as Judas would expect? Was he not trying to tell Judas that he was ready to forgive the 'most unkindest kiss' provided the latter repented as Peter would do after disowning his Master?
So, the answer to the OP lies in the answer of another question: "Why did Jesus call himself the Son of Man in front of Judas ?"

No.
Judas was never saved at all. The problem is that false prophets always use Judas Iscariot to somehow prove that saved people can lose salvation.
John 6:64-71 But there are some of you that believe not. For Jesus knew from the beginning who they were that believed not, and who should betray him. And he said, Therefore said I unto you, that no man can come unto me, except it were given unto him of my Father. From that time many of his disciples went back, and walked no more with him. Then said Jesus unto the twelve, Will ye also go away? Then Simon Peter answered him, Lord, to whom shall we go? thou hast the words of eternal life. And we believe and are sure that thou art that Christ, the Son of the living God. Jesus answered them, Have not I chosen you twelve, and one of you is a devil? He spake of Judas Iscariot the son of Simon: for he it was that should betray him, being one of the twelve.
From the beginning, it was clear that Judas was NOT SAVED and the Lord said, "One of you IS a devil".
Even at that point, prior to the betrayal of our Lord, Judas Iscariot was NOT SAVED.
